# I can't deal with "IndexError: string index out of range" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def words():
quote = input("Enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ")
word = ""
for ltr in quote:
    if ltr.isalpha():
        word = word + ltr
    else:
        if word[0].lower() > "g":
            print(word.upper())
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ""
```

[Here all the info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTuto.png).

Seriously I do not know what to do.

Comment: Post your full error message.  Not a link to it, post the text please.

Comment: `word[0].lower` will throw out the error because word may be empty.

Comment: @huck_cussler Got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `word[0]` because `word` could be empty while still failing the `isalpha` check. Check for `len(word)` first:

```
if len(word) and word[0].lower() > 'g':
```

Comment: Note: I think you don't even need `len()`, since non-empty word is truthy. So `if word and world[0]...` should be sufficient too.